# How do you derive the Bethe-Salpeter equation / Dyson-Schwinger equations?

Tags: quantum-field-theory

I am wondering how to derive the (homogenous) [Bethe-Salpeter equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bethe%E2%80%93Salpeter_equation)
$$
\Gamma(P,p) =\int\!\frac{d^4k}{(2\pi)^4} \; K(P,p,k)\, S(k-\tfrac{P}{2}) \,\Gamma(P,k)\, S(k+\tfrac{P}{2})
$$
and from what I understand, it's possible to do this via the Dyson-Schwinger equations. But there lies the next problem: while trying to derive the Dyson-Schwinger equation (say for the electron propagator in QED), I get so far as
$$
\bigg[\left.\frac{\delta S[\varphi]}{\delta\varphi_k}\right|_{\varphi\to\delta/(\text i\delta J)}+J_k\bigg]Z[J]=0,
$$
but I simply can't derive the "typical" form
$$
S(p)=S_{0}(p)+S_{0}(p)\left(e^{2}\int {\frac {d^{4}k}{(2\pi )^{4}}}\gamma _{\mu }D^{\mu \nu }(p-k)S(k)\Gamma _{\nu }(p,k)\right)S(p) ,
$$
I would be really grateful if someone could link me a PDF/document/webpage where I can follow the steps.

See [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/305533/how-to-get-dyson-schwinger-equations-for-quantum-electrodynamics) for a similar (but unanswered) question.

---

I tried to follow [this PDF](https://inspirehep.net/record/849701/files/849701.pdf), section 1.4.1, but I don't follow, what happens at eq.(1.66)$\to$(1.67) and the end result (1.73) also looks kinda different to what I want...